# kie-maven-plugin for gradle 5.2.1

Tags: drools

I have seen many examples kie-maven-plugin using maven. But i want to know how to make a plugin kie-maven-plugin in gradle project. Seems like that plugin is not avilable in gradle core plugin. I appriciate if someone share github project link

Comment: Hi @Deepika, you can see the corresponding gradle dependency from the maven repository postal. Select the version and copy the content from gradle tab "compile group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-maven-plugin', version: '7.36.1.Final"